# Represent database records with multiple field names together in web2oy

Tags: web2py

Say I have a db model as such:

```
db.define_table('company',
    Field('name', notnull=True, unique=True), 
    Field('address', notnull=True),
    format='%(name)s')
```

How can I make a record represented with not only its `name`, but also along with its `address`, just like `"ABC Ltd - New York"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format` argument can be (a) a Python format string, which will have the `Row` object (which acts like a dictionary) applied to it, or (b) a function that takes the `Row` object and returns the desired representation.

In this case, you can do:

```
format='%(name)s - %(address)s'
```

See https://pyformat.info/#named_placeholders (web2py uses the old style).